# How to integrate automated selenium tests with AzureDevOps pipeline

Tags: maven, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to integrate automated tests with AzureDevOps.
That way, each time you run the pipeline, the tests will be executed and the results updated in AzureDevOps.
But im not getting success.
My project:

- Maven
- Junit4
- Eclipse
- Java
- Surefire plugin
- Selenium

I tried to run de build the pipeline using the Maven task as you can see below:
[Pipeline Tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BycN.png)

and the goal "test":

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM5bv.png)

I also tried "clean test".

But only the "package" objective worked, the other options run the build and they work, but they don't run the tests.

Hopefully someone knows how to get the pipeline to trigger the web browser and actually run the tests given the technologies I'm using.

Anyway, if there's a solution that changes some of the tools I'm using, but is simpler to implement, I'll take it!

Comment: Hi crystian, I have several factors to confirm with you. 1.Does your test succeeded on your local machine? 2.Are you running the pipeline via Microsoft-hosted agent or Selfhosted agent? Does it work if you run with Selfhosted agent? 3.Could you share the related warning message or pom.xml and yaml definition? You could also look into this doc for reference [Selenium Test with Pom](https://octopus.com/blog/selenium/2-the-maven-pom-file/the-maven-pom-file)